# Basic array iteration in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in for format as below (consol.log in browser). How would I iterate the array in php?

```
stdClass Object
(
    [SIEcat7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => test1
            [amount] => 1 000.00

        )

    [SIEcat8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [text] => test2
            [amount] => 0.00

        )



)
```

Comment: `echo implode(',', array_keys($array));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below.

```
<?php 
    foreach ($array as $key => $arr){
        echo 'Key: ' , $key, '<br>'; #This will print the keys SIEcat7, SIEcat8
        echo 'Text: ', $arr->text, '<br>';
        echo 'amount: ', $arr->amount, '<br> -------- <br>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it now

```
foreach($data as $i => $item) {

}
```